# conditional python; Time format newer than 30 minutes

Tags: python

I have a variable that has a stored created date as:

```
2022-09-01T19:40:17.268980742Z
```

In python, if i wanted to look at that time and say if 'created' is within than the last 30 minutes, do X.

*EDIT*
I have another command I can use (working within Palo XSOAR), that will give me the current date time in ISO.

So really want I'm trying to do is say:

```
if created is within the last 30 minutes:
   do X
```

Assume I have to capture current time as ISO variable (can do)
Set a variable less than 30 minutes of the current time (not sure)
then if create time is between those two values do X (not sure)

Any help is appreciated -

Thanks,

Comment: [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Comment: And, what is the problem? What code have you tried? Can you even parse the timestamp?

Comment: I'm confused on this format:  2022-09-01T19:40:17.268980742Z

is this a string and I need to format it to a date and time format?

haven't played much with python

Comment: That's the ISO8601 standard format. See `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datetime.now()` to get the current datetime. We can then coerce your datetime string into a datetime object, too. Then, we can look at the difference and apply some logic.

```
import datetime 

some_string = '2022-09-01T19:40:17.268980742Z'
some_string = some_string.split('.')[0]
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(some_string)

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()

if (current_time - timestamp) < timedelta(minutes=30):
    print('x')

else:
    print('y')
```

Here are how the variables look:

```
>>> print(timestamp)
datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 1, 19, 40, 17)

>>> print(current_time)
datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 5, 4, 26, 14, 345147)

>>> print(current_time - timestamp)
datetime.timedelta(days=3, seconds=31557, microseconds=345147)
```

---

Note, I wasn't able to convert the provided timestamp of `2022-09-01T19:40:17.268980742Z` to a datetime object using the `fromisoformat`. Trimming down the microseconds six decimal places worked fine, but seven throws an error. This is expected for datetime objects as the permissable resolution is `Between 0 and 999999 inclusive` (src: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

This is why I split the string.

Works:

```
some_string = '2022-09-01T19:40:17.268980'
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(some_string)
```

Error:

```
some_string = '2022-09-01T19:40:17.2689801'
timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(some_string)
```